# Hot to unset or delete the values in an nested array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{  "_id" : 1,
   "grades" : [
      { "grade" : [90], "mean" : 75, "std" : 5 },
      { "grade" : [0,a,f,g,w], "mean" : 100, "std" : 4 },
      { "grade" : [1,2,3,4], "mean" : 100, "std" : 5 }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "grades" : [
      { "grade" : [3,4,5,6], "mean" : 100, "std" : 5 },
      { "grade" : [a,s,d,f], "mean" : 100, "std" : 3 },
      { "grade" : [g,a,s,e,f], "mean" : 100, "std" : 4 }
   ]
}
```

Above is the document which is present in a collection called "Project", I need to write a query which will delete or empty the values of the array "grade".
How shall I do it and what is the query needs to be written to empty the "grades" array?

Comment: can you please update your question and add your desired output. do you want to update your collection or query the results?

Comment: empty it and then get the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset all `grade` arrays then you want to use the [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator like so:

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, {$set: {"grades.$[].grade": []}})
```

Comment: for the same collection like above, after i run the query you gave me
what if i want to get all the documents where the "grade" array is not empty?

Comment: After you run the query I just posted every syntax `grade` array will be empty in the collection meaning no document match what you just wrote, is this not what you asked for?